# Parse multiple files with javascript: the same file in for-loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have such code:

```
    function processFiles(e) {

      var filesInput = $('#files').prop('files');
      var i, f;

      for (i = 0, f = filesInput[i]; i != filesInput.length; ++i) {

        var name = f.name;
        console.log(name); //why here is the same file, even if i select in file input 2 different?

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
          var myFile = e.target.result;
          console.log(myFile);  //why here is the same file, even if i select in file input 2 different?
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
      }
    }

    $('#sbmt').click(function(e) {
      processFiles();
    });
```

but when i try to parse multiple files, i got the same file in for loop & .onload callback

what i do wrong?

Comment: Consider reading as arrayBuffer instead... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString `readAsBinaryString` was removed from the standard and not all browser has it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why here is the same file, even if i select in file input 2 different?

Because nothing updates `f` in the `for` loop. You've set `f` in the initialization expression, but you don't update it in the update expression.

If you want to use the `for` to control `f`, be sure you update `f`:

```
for (i = 0, f = filesInput[i]; i != filesInput.length; ++i, f = filesInput[i]) {
// -------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...but at that point, you're duplicating code; instead, I'd just move the sssignment into the loop body:

```
for (i = 0; i != filesInput.length; ++i) {
    f = filesInput[i]
```

...or more likely I'd probably use `forEach`:

```
function processFiles(e) {
    Array.from($('#files').prop('files')).forEach(function(f) {
        var name = f.name;

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            var myFile = e.target.result;
            console.log(myFile);
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
    });
}
```

(Note that that uses `Array.from` from ES2015; you'll need a polyfill to use that in the wild for now...)

Comment: thank's 
btw: how can i concat all files into one, after all files were read?

Comment: @brabertaser19: Just concatenate the binary strings.

Comment: problem)) in reader.onload i'm parsing .xlsx file, and there i fetch some data, and as result i need to create one file with data from all files...

Comment: @brabertaser19: Manipulating data from Excel files is well beyond the scope of this question. Once you've had a go at doing it, post a new question with the details.

Answer (score 1):

My 2 cents:
Took a crack at using Response (part of the new fetch api) to get the buffer with help of es6 and Promises

```
function processFiles(e) {
  let files = $('#files')[0].files
  let buffers = [...files].map(file => new Response(file).arraybuffer())

  Promise.all(buffers).then(buffers => {
    // concatinate(buffers)
  })
}
```